# Sort columns numerically in R

Tags: r, string, sorting

I have data that looks like the following, except the numbers are out of order:

```
dat<-
paste("Experience",1:20,sep="_")
```

Basically, I am trying to sort the columns in numerical order based on the ending number to order them as the code above produces. However, when I `sort` the values, it sorts based on the first digit as such:

```
"Experience_1"  "Experience_10"  "Experience_11" "Experience_12" 
"Experience_13" "Experience_14"  "Experience_15" "Experience_16" 
"Experience_17" "Experience_18" "Experience_19" "Experience_2" 
"Experience_20" "Experience_3"  "Experience_4"  "Experience_5" 
"Experience_6"  "Experience_7" "Experience_8"  "Experience_9"
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I dont quite understand. can you provide a minimal example of (i) how your dataframe currently looks like and (ii) what the intended dataframe should look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Stringr library, a part of the tidyverse, has `str_sort()` which sorts strings numerically in `R`.

```
library(stringr)
str_sort(dat, numeric = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

An option would be `mixedsort` from `gtools`

```
gtools::mixedsort(dat)
#[1] "Experience_1"  "Experience_2"  "Experience_3"  "Experience_4"  "Experience_5"  "Experience_6" 
#[7] "Experience_7"  "Experience_8"  "Experience_9"  "Experience_10" "Experience_11" "Experience_12"
#[13] "Experience_13" "Experience_14" "Experience_15" "Experience_16" "Experience_17" "Experience_18"
#[19] "Experience_19" "Experience_20"
```